# Show three nonlinear equations have finitely many solutions

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Let $0<p<1$, $\lambda>0$, $x_1 \neq 0$, $x_2\neq 0$, $x_1 - c_1 \neq 0$, $x_2 - c_2 \neq 0$, $\xi>0$. Also, either $c_1\neq 0$ or $c_2 \neq 0$ but both cannot be zero simultaneously. Can we show the following system of nonlinear equations has finitely many solutions?:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p\,\text{sign}(x_1)|x_1|^{p-1}+\lambda(x_1-c_1)&=0\\
p\,\text{sign}(x_2)|x_2|^{p-1}+\lambda(x_2-c_2)&=0\\
(x_1-c_1)^2+(x_2-c_2)^2 &= \xi^2
\end{aligned}
$$

**My try:**
From the first and second equations we get the following :
$$
\frac{p^2(|x_1|^{2(p-1)}+|x_2|^{2(p-1)})}{\lambda^2}=\xi^2
$$
where squaring the terms eliminates $\text{sign}(x_1)$ and $\text{sign}(x_2)$.
Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are on a circle, they are bounded. Also, according to our assumptions, they cannot be zero so the numerator of the left hand side is bounded which implies $\lambda$ should be bounded.

**Note:**

For rational number specially $p=1/2$, it can be shown that it has finitely many solutions. I am interested in the non restricted case where $p$ can take irrational numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  guess that you assume that $c_1$, $c_2$ (and not $x_1-c_1$, $x_2-c_2$) are non null, and that the unknowns are $x_1$ and $x_2$?

For all real number $x$, set $f(x) = p~\mathrm{sign}(x)~|x|^{p-1} + \lambda x$. Then $f(x)$ has the same sign as $x$. When $x \ne 0$, $f'(x) = p(p-1)|x|^{p-2} + \lambda$ has the same sign as $|x|^{p-2} - \lambda/[p(1-p)]$, namely the same sign as $x_0-|x|$, where
$$x_0 := \Big(\frac{\lambda}{p(1-p)}\Big)^{1/(p-2)}.$$
Therefore $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,-x_0]$ and on $[x_0,+\infty)$ and decreasing on $[-x_0,0)$ and on $(0,x_0]$.

As a result, the first equation has at most two solutions $x_1$, the second equation has at most two solutions $x_2$, so the system has at most four solutions $(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. What do you mean $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not null? Do you mean nonzero? Why $f(x)$ that you have defined does not include $\lambda c_1$?

Comment: @Sepide Yes, I meant different of zero, so if I understood correctly, you should edit your question to correct it. Your first two equations can be written $f(x_1) = \lambda c_1$ and $f(x_2) = \lambda c_2$.

Comment: there is also a typo $[x_0, -\infty)$ should be $[x_0, \infty)$.

Comment: @Sepide I have just corrected it. Are you convinced?

Comment: I believe so. I need to think about it and may come back to you with some questions, but for the time being I granted the score for your solution as well as endorsement.

Comment: either $c_1$ or $c_2$ can be zero but both cannot be zero simultaneously. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @Sepide No difference. The variations of $f$ shows that each real number (positive, null, or negative) can be reached at most twice by $f$.

Comment: how would you show $f'(x)$ has the same sign as $x_0-|x|$? Shouldn't $x_0$ be $(\frac{p(1-p)}{\lambda})^{\frac{1}{2-p}}$?

Comment: @Sepide Yes, I had omitted an exponent. I have just corrected my formula for $x_0$, which is equivalent to yours.

Comment: We have only shown that first two equations, **for a fixed $\lambda>0$** , have finitely many solutions. Any solution to the first two equations is a function of $\lambda>0$, so the last equation becomes, $(x_1(\lambda)-c_1)^2+(x_2(\lambda)-c_2)^2 = \xi^2$, how do we know the last equation has finitely many solution? We know $\lambda>0$ and bounded.

Comment: @Sepide $\lambda$ is unknown? You should precise it and edit your question to correct mistakes and imprecisions. Look at the beginning of my answer « I guess that you assume that 1, 2 (and not 1−1, 2−2) are non null, and that the unknowns are 1 and 2? ».

Comment: @Sepide Anyway, you can write $$p^2(|x_1|^{2p-2}+|x_2|^{2p-2}) = \lambda^2[(x_1-c_1)^2+(x_2-c_2)^2] = \lambda^2 \xi^2.$$

Comment: how do we know the above equation for any $p$ irrational or rational and $\lambda>0$ has finitely many solutions when $\lambda$ varies? for any $\lambda$ we have finitely many $x_1$ and $x_2$, but if $\lambda$ takes infinitely many values then we have infinitely many solutions? How would you rule out the last variant? $\lambda$ is bounded but it can vary in $0<\lambda <u$ where $u$ is its upper bound.

Comment: @Sepide Before thinking anymore to this problem, I want its statement to be clear : what is supposed to be known, what is unknown : $x_1,x_2,\lambda$?

Comment: that is right. We have a nonlinear system of equations of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $\lambda$, these three last ones are variable and unknown. $p$, $c_1$, $c_2$, and $\xi$ are given values.

Comment: any update about the question?